# rospack 2dnav_pr2

Tags: ros, tutorial, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to follow this Tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects#roslaunch.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-Roslaunch_tips_for_larger_projects.Top-level_organization

And when There is written to do :

```
******@************:~$ rospack find 2dnav_pr2/move_base/2dnav_pr2.launch
```

I have the following error:

```
[rospack] Error: package '2dnav_pr2/move_base/2dnav_pr2.launch' not found
```

Someone could help me to solve this problem?

I know that probably it is an easy one but I am not able to go on.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198132/rospack-2dnav_pr2/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your goal is actually to run PR2 navigation, the package is called pr2_2dnav, and is documented on [its wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_2dnav).

If you're just looking for info on roslaunch, I don't think that tutorial was really written to actually be run, but rather as an example of how to organize launch files for large projects which you can adapt for your own project.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil123456](https://answers.ros.org/users/51234/phil123456/) on 2020-02-08**:
the tutorial should at least include instructions to install the package - people will obviously use this as a starter for their robot project - not being able to figure things in real life, just by reading is not great as a learning experience